# SwaggerUI 5.0.0 ignoring JsonProperty name

Tags: json.net, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I recently upgraded a ASP.NET Core API application to Swashbuckle/Swagger 5.0.0 with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0" />
```

However, upon doing so I have noticed that the Swagger UI is now ignoring the Newtonsoft/JSON.NET JsonProperty attribute names on DTO properties.  For example:

```cs
[HttpGet("testget", Name = "testget")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public ActionResult<TestGetResponse> TestGet()
{
    var response = new TestGetResponse { MyName = "John" };

    return Ok(response);
}

public class TestGetResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string MyName { get; set; }
}
```

Is outputting in Swagger UI as:

Code 200:
Example Value

```
Model
{
  "myName": "string"
}
```

Instead of Model property name `name`.

For Swagger in Startup.cs ConfigureServices I currently have:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "My API",
    });

    c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
});
```

And for Swagger in Startup.cs Configure I currently have:

```cs
app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
    c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
});
```

I am aware that if I use the `System.Text.Json` attribute `JsonPropertyName` instead this will be fixed however I need to stick with the original attributes for now.

Is there a setting in Start.cs to tell SwaggerUI to use the Newtonsoft JsonProperty attribute or is there something I need to change at the ASP.NET Core level of configuration?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It would appear that full support for NewtonSoft JSON.net from version 5.0.0 of Swashbuckle/Swagger is provided through a separate package.

To get this working:

1) Install the nuget package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` version 5.0.0+

2) In Startup.ConfigureServices() make a call for the support:

`services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();`

Further info can be found [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft).

Comment: I think though this explanation is older, I've tried this and still not finding success. I'm running version 5.5.1 of the swagger packages. Anyone have further notes on this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem with Asp.Net Core 3.1 and NSwag Nuget package. When I try from Postman everything is fine, but from Swagger UI it passes the placeholders in request instead of param values and it does not recognizes the JsonProperty("MyName") in a querystring parameter.

Comment: @bytedev What do you mean by not calling `AddNewtonsoftJson`? Is it how aspnetcore configure to use newtonsoftjson package?

Comment: @liang thanks for spotting the mix up. i've deleted my old comment.